# Rust how to ignore print to stdout error?

Tags: windows, rust, signals, msys2, sigpipe

How do I ignore pipe errors in Rust? In C, this comes for free:

```
user@localhost:~ $ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("Hello World!\n");}
user@localhost:~ $ clang main.c -o main
user@localhost:~ $ ./main.exe | echo && echo $?

0
user@localhost:~ $
```

But with Rust, its default behavior is to panic on a bad pipe:

```
user@localhost:~ $ cat main.rs
fn main(){println!("Hello World!");}
user@localhost:~ $ rustc main.rs
user@localhost:~ $ ./main.exe | echo && echo $?

thread 'main' panicked at library\std\src\io\stdio.rs:1021:9:
failed printing to stdout: The pipe is being closed. (os error 232)
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
0
user@localhost:~ $
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760807) suggests reseting the `SIGPIPE` handler, but that is not useful for me as I'm on Windows. I am running `zsh` in MSYS2 as my shell, but the underlying OS is still Windows, so the symbol `libc::SIGPIPE` still can't be resolved - plus I get the same error running the program from CMD or powershell, so I doubt its a shell problem.

Is there a way I can make my Rust program ignore `SIGPIPE` errors, as my C program does?

Comment: `echo` does not read from `stdin`, so output has nowhere to go. Why do you want to change that behavior?

Comment: If you want to ignore output, you can explicitly pass it to `/dev/null`. As in `./main > /dev/null | echo`.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze While that is true, I do not want my program to crash when a user tries to pipe it somewhere invalid, such as `echo`. In C I don't need any special handling to prevent my app from crashing due to user error. I'm hoping to have my Rust program behave similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `writeln!` macro instead of `println!` and handle (or ignore) the errors yourself:

```rust
fn main() {
    let stdout = std::io::stdout();
    // ignore errors (assign to _ to silence the warning)
    let _ = writeln!(stdout, "Hello World!");
}
```

`println!(format_str)` essentially resolves to something like

```rust
writeln!(std::io::stdout(), format_str, ...).unwrap();
```